# Допустимо ли в одном месте использовать ключевое слово `struct`, а в другом `class` для указания одного типа?

Tags: c++, стандарт

Допустимо ли в одном месте использовать ключевое слово `struct`, а в другом `class` для указания одного типа?

```
struct A {
    class A* ptr;
};
```

Comment: А зачем во второй строчке слово `class`?...

Comment: @HarryfromKiev для примера, что я имею в виду

Comment: VC++ дает warning C4099. А вообще, см. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4866425/9123401

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кланг выдает варнинг:

`warning: class 'A' was previously declared as a struct; this is valid, but may result in linker errors under the Microsoft C++ ABI [-Wmismatched-tags]`

Так что видимо легально, но может не работать в MSVC.